# Pence in the pound

Tags: phrases

I have received correspondence that includes the sentence:

> The buyer (or debt collection agency) will offer you pence in the pound irrespective of how I reply.

What does "Pence in the pound" mean?

Comment: It's likely a typo or mistranscription for  *pence **on** the pound*, or for Americans like me *pennies on the dollar*. That is, for every pound (dollar) the item is actually worth, they agency will only give you a handful of pence (pennies) for it. They'll only pay you a small percent of what it's worth.

Comment: Could be. We need more information about the type of deal to be certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unusual usage -- normally pence in the pound refers to tax rates when it's equivalent to percent.  Here it's more like an anglicised ["pennies on the dollar"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/29716/48571) (related question) meaning a small fraction of the nominal value.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Pence in the pound***
>
> *I’ve just watched the news tonight, and apparently today the Bank of*
>   *England dropped the base interest rate to “one and half pence in the*
>   *pound.”*
>
> *I’m totally shocked ...*
>
> *If was measuring anything else but money, of course, it would be 1.5%.*
>
> [Matt Godbolt's blog](http://xania.org/200901/pence-in-the-pound-why)

It is a measure of how many pennies per pound are gained or lost in some financial transaction.

**Examples**

*Income tax has risen by one and a half pence in the pound.* (1.5%)

*This investment will yield 10 pence in the pound annually.* (10%)

*There will be a reduction in the price of milk of 2 pence in the pound.*  (2%)

etc.

Comment: Very interesting. Could this definition with "in" fit in the example? perhaps the author confused the two expressions and did in fact mean "pence on the pound". I suppose we need more context.

Comment: It is very dated, in Britain, to use this expression - pence in the pound. Nowadays almost everything of this kind is expressed as a percentage. Incidentally the *Bank of England's* base rate is 0.5% (not 1.5%) and has been for the last 6 or 7 years (since the crash).